# How to get ROS version?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
is there a way how to get ROS version which I'm using. I mean not the one of electric, fuerte and so on, but if I'm using beta or not?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33769/how-to-get-ros-version?/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 22

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bi613en](https://answers.ros.org/users/22564/bi613en/) on 2018-04-19**:
As this is a popular question and a top google result, maybe the accepted answer should be changed to a current solution, like the [one](https://answers.ros.org/question/33769/how-to-get-ros-version/?answer=194487#post-id-194487) presented by [merosss](https://answers.ros.org/users/14411/merosss/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of Indigo the correct command for **ROS1** is:

```
rosversion -d
```

For **ROS2** instead use:

```
echo $ROS_DISTRO
```

---

Originally posted by [merosss](https://answers.ros.org/users/14411/merosss/) with karma: 723 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 59

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2016-01-14**:
`rosversion -d`

also works for hydro

**Comment by [willSapgreen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26619/willsapgreen/) on 2016-05-01**:
rosversion -d gives me "jade"
rosversion roscpp gives me "1.11.16"
Does it mean I am using 1.11.16 jade version?
Thank you

**Comment by [lhnguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/27813/lhnguyen/) on 2016-09-02**:
work for Kinetic

**Comment by [breandan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32982/breandan/) on 2019-03-23**:
This does not work on ROS2.

**Comment by [merosss](https://answers.ros.org/users/14411/merosss/) on 2019-03-23**:
@breandan I've updated the answer ;)

**Comment by [raj199322](https://answers.ros.org/users/47159/raj199322/) on 2020-04-30**:
Thanks. It also worked for indigo

**Comment by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) on 2022-05-11**:
It also works for noetic

Comment: I don't know who is managing the db migration, but I'm the merosss of the original answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rosversion ros
```

This will print a version number. The current Fuerte release has version number 1.8. Everything above should be unstable at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-11**:
To clarify: it currently prints 1.8.6, anything starting with 1.9.0 should be unstable. You should not see the unstable version unless you explicitly install it.

**Comment by [salman](https://answers.ros.org/users/4325/salman/) on 2013-04-08**:
It says

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-09**:
It fails for me on Hydro, too. That may be a new bug. It should say 1.10.0. Probably worth a defect ticket: https://github.com/ros/ros/issues/new

**Comment by [leo pauly](https://answers.ros.org/users/11031/leo-pauly/) on 2014-02-23**:
for me too it says < unversioned >

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-02-23**:
It has to be an actual package name. I don't think there is a package named **ros** any more. Try it with `rosversion roscpp`.

**Comment by [bhanu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22691/bhanu/) on 2015-12-18**:
rosvrrsion roscpp works perfectly for hydro, thanks

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-08-18**:
$ rosversion ros

with current kinetic (1.12.2) mmh?

**Comment by [antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23427/antonio/) on 2017-04-14**:
For me (ros jade on Ubuntu 14.04) this just prints "Cannot locate [ros]"

**Comment by [OrnellaT](https://answers.ros.org/users/70672/ornellat/) on 2021-03-29**:
Same for me  :

```
$ rosversion -d
noetic
$ rosversion ros
<unversioned>
$ rosversion roscpp 
1.15.9
```